# dask xgboost giving different answers compared to xgboost

Tags: dask, xgboost, dask-distributed

I am running the same piece of code on Normal XGBoost and Dask XGBoost. 
I am getting different probabilities from both models.

Normal XGBoost Code

```
params = {'objective': 'binary:logistic', 'nround': 1000,
      'max_depth': 16, 'eta': 0.01, 'subsample': 0.5,
      'min_child_weight': 1, 'tree_method': 'hist',
      'grow_policy': 'lossguide'}
model = XGBClassifier(params=params)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

Output:-[Normal XGBoost Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LIIE.png)

Dask XGBoost Code

```
params = {'objective': 'binary:logistic', 'nround': 1000,
      'max_depth': 16, 'eta': 0.01, 'subsample': 0.5,
      'min_child_weight': 1, 'tree_method': 'hist',
      'grow_policy': 'lossguide'}
bst = dxgb.train(client, params, X_train, y_train)
predictions2 = dxgb.predict(client, bst, X_test).persist()
```

Output:-
[Dask XGBoost Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W605E.png)

Can someone please help me here?

Comment: I recommend providing an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then raising a bug on the dask-xgboost issue tracker.